# virtualenv with python2 and python3 via Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, homebrew

I have installed python2 and python3 with Homebrew. I would like to use virtualenv but I am not sure if I need to install it for both python2/python3. I am also wondering if I use virtualenvwrapper can I just set the VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON to be either python2 or python3 depending on my needs?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv), you could use a single `virtualenv` for both version, just use the `-p path/to/python/version` or `--python=path/to/version` flag to specify which version to use for the creation of the virtual environment. Note that you can use the same flag with `mkvirtualenv`.

[This post](http://www.insomnihack.com/?p=421) recommends to just use the system Python (2.7 in your case) to install `virtualenv` itself.

Comment: Do you mean that one can use the same virtualenv program? What I understand from the mentioned SO question, is that you need a separate virtual environment for the two Python versions.

Comment: You can have python2.x *and* python3.x in the *same* virtual environment. For example, with `virtualenvwrapper`, you can do `mkvirtualenv test; mkvirtualenv test -p /usr/local/bin/python3`; in that case, the env's `python` will point to the latest installed (python3.), but you'll still have links to both python2.x and python3.x.

Comment: This worked for me, although it was the other way around: python was left pointing to the first installed version, and I have to call python3 explicitly.