# Installing pip3 with a virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, python-3.3

I am trying to clean up a few things now that I have Mavericks. I used Homebrew to install python 2.7 and 3.3. I also have their respective pips. Now I want to have a sane virtualenv setup.

I see from [virtualenv with python2 and python3 via Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566064/virtualenv-with-python2-and-python3-via-homebrew) that I can specify which version of python a newly-created virtualenv will use. What is the best (i.e., easiest to use/remember) way to make sure that a virtualenv using Python 3.3 uses pip3?

ETA: I've not had to use 3.3 before, so this is my first experience trying to maintain different versions. Sorry if this has an obvious answer.

Comment: Execute in your shell "which python" and you will guess the version. You can name your environments as follows: <project>-<python-version>

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean to imply that because the Homebrew Python 3.3 install includes pip3, setting up a virtualenv with that install will automatically include its pip3? I wasn't taking that for granted. If so, awesome.

Comment: I’m not sure how that comment implies that, but yes, you’re right – pip should be installing to the right virtualenv either way, since it’s installed as part of the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article: [Python Development Environment on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/). It describes quite clearly how to set up both versions of Python on the same machine using Homebrew and contains some helpful pointers.

In the article, the author appends *-py3* to a Python3 virtualenv, as @moliware already suggested.

Comment: Yes, thank you -- I actually did run across that while doing further research after @moliware's initial comment made me question my assumptions.

Comment: what was `mkvirtualenv -ppython3.3 some_name` for me

Answer (score 6):

Credit goes to [scythargon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531116/scythargon) for this one (left in a comment to [Kristof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3165737/kristof)'s [answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029090/1149774)) and, since it did exactly what I needed, I figured it deserved its own answer.

When creating a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper use the -p flag to explicitly associate it with a specific version of Python. In the examples below replace {virtualenv_name} with your intended virtual environment name:

Python 3.3:

```
$ mkvirtualenv {virtualenv_name} -ppython3.3
```

Python 3.4:

```
$ mkvirtualenv {virtualenv_name} -ppython3.4
```

Python 2.7:

```
$ mkvirtualenv {virtualenv_name} -ppython2.7
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine, this worked by removing ```mk```. Eg - ```virtualenv env -ppython3.3```