# Is it possible to use the same pipenv for both python2 and python3?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` to isolate a setup I would like to use later: I used `pip` to install jupyter lab, and would like to use kernels for both `python2` and `python3` from it.

However, I was not able to nest those virtual environments, and for now I am using some system-wide packages for `python2`.

Is there a simple way to combine multiple `pipenv` for that use case? The way it works with paths, I don't see any technical obstacle to it.

A related question regarding `virtualenv` was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782537/create-a-virtualenv-with-both-python2-and-python3).

Comment: The main concept that virtual environments are implementing is isolation. What you are trying to do is the opposite of that.

Comment: Not really, I am trying to isolate an environment that has a set of tools: `python2`, `python3`, and related pip packages. If I see python 2 and 3 as completely distinct, like jupyter does, that shouldn't cause any problems. If there is no easy answer with `pipenv`, I will probably hack my `PATH` manually, or install these tools in a container.

Answer (score 0):

I would steer away from using the same virtualenv location for different python versions. Per the same [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011757/5611494) you linked to.

If you need to manage different python versions from the same directory, I would suggest looking into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local-advanced).