# Pyenv: `python3.6 -m venv venv` creates an environment with Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-venv, pyenv

I am having some trouble with creating virtual environments using pyenv.

This works fine:

```sh
$ pyenv local 3.6.0
$ python
>>> Python 3.6.0 (default, Jul 21 2019, 14:03:29)
>>> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
>>> ...
```

But then when I create a virtual environment (which I assume done with Python 3.6.0) and activate it, I get Python 3.7.4. The same happens if I use `python3.6 -m venv venv`.

```sh
$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python
>>> Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23)
>>> [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
```

Putting that into words, I want to create a virtual environment with the same version that is currently active via pyenv. What am I missing here?

Some info to my system:

- I am on macOS.
- I have installed Python 3.7.4 via Homebrew, and it's the default version for `python3`.
- If I call `python` only without having activated pyenv in my shell, I get Python 2.7.16 interpreter.

Comment: I have now realized that the system clock is also messed up :P

Comment: what version do you have when you call `python3.6` in a bare terminal (no venv activated)?

Comment: @Derlino 3.6.0. If I don't load the pyenv intialization script when I start a new shell session, `python3.6` fails.

Comment: Check the `README.md` from the project's repo. `pyenv` is not setup correctly on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

> If I call python only without having activated pyenv in my shell, I get Python 2.7.16 interpreter.

This means shims from `pyenv` is not added into the `PATH` environment.

`pyenv` need to be initialized in your shell conf with following code,

```sh
if command -v pyenv &>/dev/null; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

if command -v pyenv-virtualenv &>/dev/null; then
  "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

After that, restart your shell. `pyenv` will work as expected.

Check [basic setup from `pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) from the project's repo for more info.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782537/create-a-virtualenv-with-both-python2-and-python3/56947744#56947744), and what you should do is:

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/your/python/version/exectuable ENV
```

Comment: I don't have virtualenv installed. Can the same be accomplished with the built-in venv module?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is why venv isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: @DPinto - yes, you can use this with venv module, as I know.

Comment: @Derlin - no. the question was "I want to create a virtual environment with the same version that is currently active", meaning "how" and not "why".
But for the "why" question - I think that venv take the executable from the path, and that way you can overwrite it.